# secp256k1 library building for C++

Tags: compiling, secp256k1, library

The title says it all. How can I compile secp256k1 for use in a personal project. I have `#include secp256k1.h` but keep getting unresolved external linkers. I believe this is due to the lack of a compiled library. I have never compiled a library before and was looking for some guidance. I am on windows 11 and have not tried to compile this library only dragged and dropped the downloaded github repo. looking for some guidance on how to compile this library.

The library: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1

Many thanks

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more information. What steps did you take? What do you exactly see? What operating system is this on? Update your questions with more details.